# When trying to deploy Django project on Azure through GitHub Repository, I'm getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'"

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-web-app-service

After I tried to deploy my Django website on Azure through GitHub, Deployment got successful and I'm not able to see the output, I'm getting Application Error. I'm using CONDA environment to run my project so I do not have requirements.txt file but I do have environment.yml file.

I tried checking in diagnostics it says Application crashed and the error is [Application Crashed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23A73.png)

2023-10-15T00:05:56.422910225Z from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application2023-10-15T00:05:56.422913932Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'2023-10-15T00:05:56.423461446Z [2023-10-15 00:05:56 +0000] [76] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 76)
and the it says that "This error is due to the missing package 'django' in the requirements.txt file. To resolve this, add the missing package in the requirements.txt file and redeploy the application."

I've attached image for application logs.[Application Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAJX5.png)

my environment.yml file is
name: SERVIR_AppTemplate
channels:

- defaults
- conda-forge
  dependencies:
- python=3.9
- django=4.1
- django-allauth
- django-import-export
- netcdf4
- shapely
- earthengine-api
- beautifulsoup4
- whitenoise
- aiohttp
- pip=23.2.1
- pip:

  - climateserv==0.0.24
    prefix: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SERVIR_AppTemplate

Comment: Please provide your GitHub URL(if you don't have any sensitive information).

Comment: Thank you for your reply @pravallika, It's a private repository I cannot share the like I'm sorry for that. The issue has been solved after generating requirements.txt file after that I'm getting error installing gdal if you have any leads please help me with the issue you can find the error details here{https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77305105/error-while-installing-gdal-in-github-actions-while-deploying-to-azure}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is a common one for those deploying Django applications on Azure from a Conda environment. The Azure deployment process looks for a `requirements.txt` file by default to install Python packages, and since you're using a Conda environment with an `environment.yml` file, the necessary packages aren't getting installed.

To resolve this:

1. **Generate a `requirements.txt` from Conda environment**:

   ```bash
   conda list --export > requirements.txt
   ```

   This will generate a `requirements.txt` file. This file might contain package versions that are specific to Conda and might not be available on PyPi. Therefore, you will have to manually adjust the versions in the `requirements.txt` file, if necessary.
2. **Adjust the `requirements.txt` file**:

   The `conda list --export` command will produce lines that aren't compatible with pip, especially lines referring to packages installed via `pip` within the Conda environment.

   You'll need to manually edit the `requirements.txt` file to ensure it contains lines that are compatible with pip. For example:

   - Replace any `=` with `==` for versioning.
   - Remove any packages that are not necessary for running your application in production.
3. **Include the `requirements.txt` in your repository**:

   Once you have the `requirements.txt` file generated and edited properly, include it in the root directory of your GitHub repository.
4. **Redeploy your application**:

   After adding the `requirements.txt` file to your repository, redeploy your application on Azure.

Comment: Thank you @Daredevil , It worked for me! but I'm getting error while installing gdal if you have some leads about this please help me with issue, you can check the issue here {https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77305105/error-while-installing-gdal-in-github-actions-while-deploying-to-azure}